# How to access ejabberd which is deployed on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang, ejabberd, ec2-api-tools

I am new to AWS. I have deployed ejabberd server on AWS ec2 ubuntu 12.04 instance correctly. I have open up the ports 5222, 5280, 5269 using aws-api-tools . Now i am unable to access ejabberd using its IP address and port 5222. I even can't access its web console. If anybody knows about the solution , help me , I stuck in this problem from 2 days.

`netstat -nap|grep erlang` , output is-

> No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.

ifconfig output is-

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:34:1f:a6:e2:20  
          inet addr:172.31.15.134  Bcast:172.31.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::34:1fff:fea6:e220/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:213969 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:305728638 (305.7 MB)  TX bytes:2912861 (2.9 MB)
          Interrupt:25 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8643 (8.6 KB)  TX bytes:8643 (8.6 KB)
```

And I am trying to connect to web admin console by this- `172.31.15.134:5280/admin`

Comment: Can you post your ejabberd configs?

Comment: I haven't change anything except providing admin name in ejabberd.cfg file. Every other setting is default setting . I am using ejabberd 2.1.13 from source.

Comment: You should provide some more information: 1. what's the output of 'netstat -nap|grep erlang'? 2. what's the output of 'ifconfig' 3. where are you trying to connect to from.

Comment: i have edited my question for your questions @giavac

Comment: Running `ifconfig` on the instance will give the machines private IP address, you need to use the public IP when connecting. You can find it in the ec2 web console.

Comment: i have tried with that also. not working.

Comment: Please run the netstat command above as root or with sudo. It'll confirm ejabberd is listening on a specific interface, or all (i.e. 0.0.0.0). If it's listening only on lo, 127.0.0.1, it won't be reachable. If it's not listening at all, it may be a configuration or setup problem. But in brief, you need to know where ejabberd is listening from. You can also experiment basic connectivity with "telnet <IP address> 5280" from the source host.

Comment: Ejabberd is not listening on any ports on running netstat. I don't know what is the configuration. I have installed ejabberd on my local system in the same way and it is accessible from other computers also. Tell me what to do . @giavac

Comment: Probably, ejabberd is not running. `ps aux|grep beam`. Look in `ejabberd.log` and `erlang.log` for the error message.